# $\gamma_5$ in non-integer dimension $D$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, spacetime-dimensions, dirac-matrices, dimensional-regularization

I need to calculate a trace containing a single $\gamma_5$ in $D$ dimensions.

The trace is given by

$$\displaylines{
\text{Tr}\bigg[ \gamma^{\alpha\tau\eta} (p_1-p_2)_\tau (p_1)_\eta \left(\gamma\cdot p_1+m_1\right)\hfill\cr \Big( -g_{\alpha\beta} +\frac{1}{3} \gamma_\alpha\gamma_\beta \Big) 
\hfill\epsilon^{\beta\mu\kappa\lambda}(p_1)_\kappa (p_3)\lambda \Big(\gamma\cdot p_3 + \gamma\cdot p_1 +m_2\Big)\gamma_5 \gamma_\mu\bigg].}$$

My first attempt was calculating it in naive dimensional regularization (NDR). In order to cancel the $\gamma_5$ matrices, I replaced $\gamma^{\alpha\tau\eta}=i\epsilon^{\alpha \tau\eta \sigma}\gamma_\sigma\gamma_5$, and I get a result with this, but sadly I  cannot find anywhere, in which scheme this relation holds true (also not in the paper I have it from). So can I use this relation in the NDR scheme or not?

My second attempt was using the Breitenlohner-Maison extension of the t'Hooft-Veltman scheme. There, I did not replace anything, since the program Feyncalc can calculate traces with odd $\gamma_5$ in $D$ dimensions using this scheme. Going through the manual of the program I found that the BMHV "scheme violates axial Ward identities and requires special model-dependent counter-terms to restore those". How do I find out how to calculate these counter-terms?

The results of my two attempts agree, but still I do not know if I can trust them or not.